# R Shiny select files from server-side directory

Tags: r, shiny

I have a folder called `logs` filled with different `.csv` files, formatted as `telemetryLog-2017.21.08.54.11.csv` (with varying dates and times at end).

For example, the above file could be stored like this: `file <- read.csv("logs/telemetryLog-1969.2017.21.08.54.11.csv", header=TRUE)`

The log files would be uploaded (in the `logs` folder, to `shinyapps.io`) along with the `ui.R` and `server.R` files. I would like to be able to obtain a list of the filenames in order to be able to select a file to display as data in a plot via `selectInput` (or any other way to list the files). The amount of files in the folder will not be an excessive amount; most likely it will be limited to around 50.

I have read the documentation for `shinyFiles` and to be completely honest I do not fully understand how the commands such as `fileGetter` or `dirGetter` work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having people browse the file system of your server, you could also use `list.files` and specify the right directory there:

```
library(shiny)
ui <-   fluidPage(
selectInput('selectfile','Select File',choice = list.files('log/')),
textOutput('fileselected')
)

server <- function(input,output)
{
  output$fileselected <- renderText({
    paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!